# Fatal error of echo a date variable that allow nulls

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to fill a HTML table with the different values of a table in SQL Server working with PHP. This is the code.

```
...
while($datosPerfil = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CPR_Name'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CON_SC_Id'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CON_Tel_Number'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CON_Startup_Date'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
}
....
```

The field "**CON_Startup_Date**" is date type and allow nulls. And this is the error that appears:

***Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string***

And when I write:

```
echo $datosPerfil['CON_Startup_Date']->format("Y-m-d");
```

It works but when arrives to a null value shows an error:

***Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on null***

Any solution that allows to run the echo for null values and correctly in date type?

Comment: why not adding a condition to check if it's null? if yes - print "(none)" if not, use the format function and print it.

Comment: First you check the value is null or not then you can pass it to the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below code :

```
while($datosPerfil = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $datosPerfil['CPR_Name'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $datosPerfil['CON_SC_Id'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $datosPerfil['CON_Tel_Number'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo (empty($datosPerfil['CON_Startup_Date'])) ? "-" : $datosPerfil['CON_Startup_Date']->format('Y-m-d');
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

More about [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: It works good and with this form I could change "-" for any character. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might as well use a `try/catch` block or simple `isset` to determine which value to display within the `<td>` that holds the `startupDate` Value like so:

```
    <?php
        //...
        while($datosPerfil = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CPR_Name'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CON_SC_Id'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CON_Tel_Number'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            try{
                $startupDate    = $datosPerfil['CON_Startup_Date']->format("Y-m-d");
            }catch(Exception $e){
                // JUST SET A DEFAULT HERE, EVEN THE STRING "UNKNOWN" MIGHT BE OK ;-)
                $startupDate    = "2016-07-12";     
            }
            echo $startupDate;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Using `isset()` the above code becomes:

```
    <?php
        //...
        while($datosPerfil = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CPR_Name'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CON_SC_Id'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $datosPerfil['CON_Tel_Number'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            // JUST SET A DEFAULT HERE, EVEN THE STRING "UNKNOWN" MIGHT BE OK ;-)
            $startupDate = isset($datosPerfil['CON_Startup_Date']) ? $datosPerfil['CON_Startup_Date']->format("Y-m-d") : "2016-07-12";
            echo $startupDate;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Comment: With the first code of try and catch prints the same error for null value. But for the second with isset() works good. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. Hope this code may be helpful for you.

```
$result=$datosPerfil['CON_Startup_Date']->format("Y-m-d");
if ($result != null) {
  echo $result;
} else { // format failed
  echo "null";
}
```

Comment: Why was this upvoted? It's still calling `format` on a (possible) null...

Comment: This code doesn't work. It prints the same error of calling a null value.